# SQL Account Balance Table

Tags: sql-server

I have a program's running account balance that updates based off a user's transactions. From this I'd like to join to a table that has rows for every user and every date of the program's history so I can get an idea of how the distribution of balances changes over time.

Ex.1 of transaction balance data(This is the end of day balance):

```
userId  transDate   userBalance
33782   2016-05-13  233
33783   2016-05-13  143
30070   2016-05-20  572
30071   2016-05-20  888
```

Ex. 2 of calendar table

```
userID  balanceDate 
33782   2016-05-13 
33783   2016-05-13 
30070   2016-05-13 
30071   2016-05-13 
33782   2016-05-20  
33783   2016-05-20  
30070   2016-05-20  
30071   2016-05-20
```

Desired Result

```
userId  balanceDate userBalance 
33782   2016-05-13  233 
33783   2016-05-13  143 
30070   2016-05-13  0
30071   2016-05-13  0 
33782   2016-05-20  233 
33783   2016-05-20  143 
30070   2016-05-20  572 
30071   2016-05-20  888
```

Basically I need to somehow join the transaction table to the calendarBalance table and have the userBalance field return the max record record where transDate is less than or equal to balanceDate otherwise 0. 
Every attempt I've made times out as the database has millions of transactions.
I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Here is an attempt that timed out:

```
SELECT d.balanceDate ,b.userId ,b.userBalance 
FROM #calendar d ,#userBalance b 
WHERE d.balanceDate >= b.transDate 
AND b.transDate >= ALL ( 
 SELECT b1.transDate 
 FROM #userBalance b1 
 WHERE b.userId = b1.userId 
 AND d.transDate >= b1.transDate 
) 
ORDER BY d.balanceDate ,b.userId
```

Comment: what if one user has several transactions within one day?

Comment: The transaction table is the sum for the date

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Can you post one of your attempts that timed out, so we can help debug it?

Comment: @TabAlleman
 SELECT d.balanceDate
 ,b.userId
 ,b.userBalance
FROM #calendar d
 ,#userBalance b
WHERE d.balanceDate >= b.transDate
 AND b.transDate >= ALL (
  SELECT b1.transDate
  FROM #userBalance b1
  WHERE b.userId = b1.userId

   AND d.transDate >= b1.transDate
  )
ORDER BY d.balanceDate

 ,b.userId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @Transaction table (UserID int,TransDate Date,UserBalance int)
Insert into @Transaction Select 33782,'2016-05-13',233
Insert into @Transaction Select 33783,'2016-05-13',143
Insert into @Transaction Select 30070,'2016-05-20',572
Insert into @Transaction Select 30071,'2016-05-20',888

Declare @Calendar table (UserID int,BalanceDate date)
Insert into @Calendar Select 33782,'2016-05-13'
Insert into @Calendar Select 33783,'2016-05-13' 
Insert into @Calendar Select 30070,'2016-05-13'
Insert into @Calendar Select 30071,'2016-05-13' 
Insert into @Calendar Select 33782,'2016-05-20'  
Insert into @Calendar Select 33783,'2016-05-20'  
Insert into @Calendar Select 30070,'2016-05-20'  
Insert into @Calendar Select 30071,'2016-05-20'  



Select A.*,UserBalance=isnull((Select top 1 UserBalance From @Transaction Where UserID=A.UserID and TransDate<=A.BalanceDate Order by TransDate Desc),0)
 From (
        Select UserID,balanceDate
         From (Select Distinct UserID from @Calendar) U
         Join (Select Distinct balanceDate  from @Calendar) C on 1=1
      ) A
 Order by 2,1 Desc
```

Returns

```
UserID  balanceDate UserBalance
33783   2016-05-13  143
33782   2016-05-13  233
30071   2016-05-13  0
30070   2016-05-13  0
33783   2016-05-20  143
33782   2016-05-20  233
30071   2016-05-20  888
30070   2016-05-20  572
```

Comment: I should add, that I don't know how this performs on a LARGE dataset.  If it does not perform well, let me know

Comment: I spot checked this and it works! Performance wise, it took 8 min 9 sec to process 14.6 million records. Given the size of the calendar table(~300 Million rows), it's going to take a while and I may just have to run in batches. I plan on only running this query once to make the initial table and then running an update script nightly for new records. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, I didn't expect 300MM rows.  I would not tolerate 8 minutes if this was a regular request,  Just let me know if I can help tune.   The select top 1 would be the killer.